# JGIT reset a file is not working in windows

Tags: windows, git, jgit, git-reset

I am using jgit in my project. My requirement is to reset a particular file. the command to do that in cli is `git reset test.txt`. I am using the following code to do it.

```
git.reset().addPath("test.txt").call();
```

it is working fine in linux but not working in windows.

please let me know if any one can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to give [git24j](https://github.com/git24j/git24j) a try, it is a straightforward operation:

```
Repository repo = Repository.open(Paths.get("path/to/your/repository"));
Index idx = repo.index();
idx.remove("test.txt", 0);
idx.write();
```

Opposite to `git add`, `git reset <path>` is basically removing `path` from git index and git24j allows you directly operating on index object.

Comment: Thank you @shijing-lv,
I don't want to pollute the repo with too many libraries  i am looking for a answer in JGIT